# Remove the comment variable from URL after posting (django)?

Tags: django

When I post a comment with the django's comment framework, I have a hidden `next` value set in hopes that once the comment is posted, it will bring the user to view their own comment.  The `next` field renders like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="http://example.com/item/1#c23" />
```

However, when a comment is posted, django is adding a `?c=23` to the end of the url so the fully formed url that the user is redirected to becomes:

```
http://example.com/item/1#c23?c=23
```

In Firefox and Safari (brief testing) this prevents the page from moving down to the correct `id=23` and just shows the very top of the page (I want it to show the just posted comment).  Removing the `?c=23` fixes the problem (by hand) but I don't know how to tell Django to stop adding it.

Ideas?

Comment: Personally, I would consider it bordering on a bug that Django gives you no way to avoid that query string (short of replacing the entire comment-posting view). I have no idea if any Django devs would agree with me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution to your problem but just wanted to add that this is a bug in Django. It would be great if you could open a ticket for it.

For 1.1, it seems [ticket 10585](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10585) took care of already existing query strings in the `next` value. That is, if `next` was `http://example.com/item/1?a=1` then it became `http://example.com/item/1?a=1?c=23` after a comment was posted. The code changes look pretty simple so you might even be able to provide a patch yourself.

Good luck!

***Update February 27, 2011***: Looks like [ticket 13411](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13411) has a patch attached!

Comment: Do you consider the best approach another hidden field in the comment form that says whether to include the `?c=` bit or not? Or rather a setting in `settings.py`?  I can see why some people would want to use it - it's just that I don't.  Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe another truth tests to see if the redirect is taking you back to the same page the comment was posted on and a `#` is present in the url?

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading your comments incorrectly but I don't see that it needs to be more complicated than identifying that there is a # fragment in the URL and inserting `?c=23` before it. That is, in your case the URL should become `http://example.com/item/1?c=23#c23` after posting the comment.

Comment: Duh!  That would, of course, be a *lot* easier.  Smile.  I'll look at that again - thanks.

Comment: Haha, now *I* am having trouble with this bug and found my own answer when googling for a solution! As it looks, the OP never opened a Django ticket :)

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery line allows you to change the current URL:

```
$(this).attr("href", "NEW_URL");
```

Replace **NEW_URL** by the new URL. You can split http://example.com/item/1#c23?c=23 using the question mark and then use the first part of the array as the new URL.